# Compressing and decompressing images when sending payload in django rest framework using lz4

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, lz4

I have the following model below. I would like to compress the document uploaded and then provide a link to the decompressed file it when a `POST` request is done. How do I use `lz4` in a class based view to compress or decompress a payload that contains images?

## models.py

```
class EmployeeDocument(models.Model):
    """
    Model, Which holds Employee documents uploaded.

    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name="employee_docs", null=True, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'DOC - %s' % (self.employee.user.username)
```